# Unable to fetch more than one pin from mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my code below where i created two datas with first pin for example 1111 and another 2222 , where if i use the first pin from the database(ie 1111) it fetches the data from mongodb and returns login successful but if i take another pin(ie 2222) it says invalid pin. May i know what is wrong with the code?

```
import pymongo

import sys

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

db = cluster['test']

collection = db['test']

login_data = int(input("Enter the pin:"))

result  = collection.find({})

for item in result:
    
    if login_data == item['pin']:
        print("Login successfully")
        break
    
    else:
        login_data != item['pin']
        print("Invalid pin")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Can you put a print(result) statement somewhere so that you can inspect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop never has chance to iterate more than once because you either `break` or `sys.exit`. Your operation can be simplified by using a filter criteria and a `find_one()`, no need for a for loop, e.g.

```
result  = collection.find_one({'pin': login_data})

if result is None:
    print("Invalid pin")
    sys.exit(0)

print("Login successfully")
```